# JSON body getting truncated inside aws lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have been getting a weird error in AWS lambda, i have implemented a post function using lambda in nodejs, which recieves an API gateway event, and then does some stuff. Below is the body:

```
{
    "toBeUpdated": [
        {
            "invoiceNumber": "305280",
            "factoryCode": "IKC",
            "invoiceStatus": "AUTOMATCH FAILED"
        }
    ],
    "nextStatus": "CANCELLED"
}
```

but when i am calling this API i keep on getting 500 from the default error catcher. On cloudwath inspection i found that the json string that i am sending is getting truncated somehow making that json invalid posting the consoled event from the logs:-

```
{"level":"INFO","message":"Event::","service":"ops-invoice-service-lambda","timestamp":"2023-10-31T14:50:52.101Z","xray_trace_id":"1-6541144c-016d98b55030452b40fbc833","awsRequestId":"54983962-589a-40f8-ac12-c6857dc86230","coldStart":false,"logStreamName":"2023/10/31/[$LATEST]42826b97a7ac4eb99f0586bcc7ce66b9","resource":"/invoices/v1/factory/bulkUpdate/v1","method":"POST","path":"/invoices/v1/factory/bulkUpdate/v1","event":{"resource":"/invoices/v1/factory/bulkUpdate/v1","path":"/invoices/v1/factory/bulkUpdate/v1","httpMethod":"POST","headers":{"Accept":"*/*","Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate, br","Accept-Language":"en-IN,en-GB;q=0.9,en;q=0.8","Content-Type":"application/json","Host":"74omm0361l.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com","Origin":"https://nike-dev.nna-ops.com","Postman-Token":"161a84b4-1c48-4ddb-9380-df3c3d371679","Referer":"https://nike-dev.nna-ops.com/","Sec-Fetch-Dest":"empty","Sec-Fetch-Mode":"cors","Sec-Fetch-Site":"cross-site","User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.1 Safari/605.1.15","X-Amzn-Trace-Id":"Root=1-6541144c-016d98b55030452b40fbc833","X-Forwarded-For":"165.225.124.149","X-Forwarded-Port":"443","X-Forwarded-Proto":"https"},"multiValueHeaders":{"Accept":["*/*"],"Accept-Encoding":["gzip, deflate, br"],"Accept-Language":["en-IN,en-GB;q=0.9,en;q=0.8"],"Content-Type":["application/json"],"Host":["74omm0361l.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"],"Origin":["https://nike-dev.nna-ops.com"],"Postman-Token":["161a84b4-1c48-4ddb-9380-df3c3d371679"],"Referer":["https://nike-dev.nna-ops.com/"],"Sec-Fetch-Dest":["empty"],"Sec-Fetch-Mode":["cors"],"Sec-Fetch-Site":["cross-site"],"User-Agent":["Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.1 Safari/605.1.15"],"X-Amzn-Trace-Id":["Root=1-6541144c-016d98b55030452b40fbc833"],"X-Forwarded-For":["165.225.124.149"],"X-Forwarded-Port":["443"],"X-Forwarded-Proto":["https"]},"queryStringParameters":null,"multiValueQueryStringParameters":null,"pathParameters":null,"stageVariables":null,"requestContext":{"resourceId":"971yrn","resourcePath":"/invoices/v1/factory/bulkUpdate/v1","operationName":"bulkUpdateByAttribute","httpMethod":"POST","extendedRequestId":"NrAb7HoBPHcEfhA=","requestTime":"31/Oct/2023:14:50:52 +0000","path":"/dev/invoices/v1/factory/bulkUpdate/v1","accountId":"266391944827","protocol":"HTTP/1.1","stage":"dev","domainPrefix":"74omm0361l","requestTimeEpoch":1698763852084,"requestId":"ff41a64b-356a-4e6d-99e6-51783d3c9dae","identity":{"cognitoIdentityPoolId":null,"accountId":null,"cognitoIdentityId":null,"caller":null,"sourceIp":"165.225.124.149","principalOrgId":null,"accessKey":null,"cognitoAuthenticationType":null,"cognitoAuthenticationProvider":null,"userArn":null,"userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.1 Safari/605.1.15","user":null},"domainName":"74omm0361l.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com","apiId":"74omm0361l"},"body":"{\n    \"toBeUpdated\": [\n        {\n            \"invoiceNumber\": \"305280\",\n            \"factoryCode\": \"IKC\",\n            \"invoi","isBase64Encoded":false}}
```

If u will look at last of the json the `body` key has a truncated json string.
If anyone can explain what is happening it would be helpful. Let me also clarify that there is sufficient memory in the lambda, there was 175MB/512MB memory utilized

Snip of last part referenced: `\"IKC\",\n            \"invoi","isBase64Encoded":false}`

Comment: Print the length to validate it. The logs might be deliberately truncated.

Comment: I am also getting unexpected end of JSON input error

Comment: API Gateway has a 10MB payload limit and AWS Lambda functions have 6 MB payload limit for synchronous invocation (and 256KB for asynchronous).

Comment: i think it is around 3100 bytes, the above is the event i printed

Comment: Send a test event with a fraction (like 10%) of the current JSON. Does it invoke with the correct payload? Note that the payload limits don't necessarily related to bytes in the original JSON as they payload ma be encoded (e.g. base64).

Comment: Can it inflate the size that much ? I believe it is already at the lowest size, the API is supposed to handle a lot more data, any ldea on what might be causing it ?

Comment: I'm simply proposing that you test with a small JSON payload to determine if payload limits are actually the root cause.

Comment: Hi there, it detected short JSON, and now it seems to have magically started working again with longer one as well, any explanations we might have for it.?

Comment: If you made no other changes and the JSON payload is the same (i.e. the same, larger size that was originally being truncated, but now works fine) then I would be concerned enough about that to consider raising a support ticket with AWS.

Comment: Sure @jarmod,  thank u so much for the help !